# Doing a repository method call in viewmodel without transformation.switchmap using GithubBrowserSample

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Google's [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/b1a194c1ae267258cd002e2e1c102df7180be473/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di) is based on if there is a search made, for it to call for the results. In my scenario, there isn't any search, I just want to call it on fragment load. However, i'm not sure how to do this. Utilising breakpoints and trial and error, I can't seem to flag it to go into the repository method I select. Any tips would be appreciated.

Some snippets of my code:

```
public class CategoryViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final LiveData<Resource<List<Category>>> categories;

    @Inject
    CategoryViewModel(@NonNull CategoryRepository categoryRepository){
        categories = categoryRepository.getDBCategories();
    }
```

Equivalent in the sample:

```
public class SearchViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> query = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private final LiveData<Resource<List<Repo>>> results;

    private final NextPageHandler nextPageHandler;

    @Inject
    SearchViewModel(RepoRepository repoRepository) {
        nextPageHandler = new NextPageHandler(repoRepository);
        results = Transformations.switchMap(query, search -> {
            if (search == null || search.trim().length() == 0) {
                return AbsentLiveData.create();
            } else {
                return repoRepository.search(search);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean "I just want to call upon it everytime"?

switchMap function is called when "query" LiveData is changed. It is probably bind to EditText, so when user type something, method is executed. In your case, you should execute code in constructor or when user clicked f.e. Button.

Comment: @MarekKondracki True, poor choice of words, I shall reword it. It is more the case of, on fragment load I would want to call upon this and then do the usual placing the results in the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else in the same boat, by simply amending the SearchViewModel constructor to hardcode the query, I was soon able to figure out that this could load even on the sample app right away as the data is being observed on the search fragment.

So I turned in SearchViewModel:

```
@Inject
SearchViewModel(RepoRepository repoRepository) {
    nextPageHandler = new NextPageHandler(repoRepository);
    results = Transformations.switchMap(query, search -> {
        if (search == null || search.trim().length() == 0) {
           return AbsentLiveData.create();
        } else {
            return repoRepository.search(search);
        }
    });
}
```

To

```
@Inject
SearchViewModel(RepoRepository repoRepository) {
    results = repoRepository.search("shadow");
    nextPageHandler = new NextPageHandler(repoRepository);
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.